# Adding Javascript function on custom aspx page

Tags: 2010, visual-studio, javascript, aspx

I have created custom ASPX page in Visual studio for my SharePoint application. I want to use JavaScript function on this custom page like this:

```
function ChangeLanguage(value) {
    var today = new Date();
    var oneYear = new Date(today.getTime() + 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    var url = window.location.href;
    document.cookie = "lcid=" + value + ";path=/;expires=" + oneYear.toGMTString();
    window.location.href = url;
}


<a href="javascript:ChangeLanguage(1053)"></a>
```

But, its not allowed to put JavaScript code in custom page. Is there any possibility to do this ?

Comment: It is definately possible to include javascript on your aspx page.  However, if this is all you are doing, you could also get away with doing it inside a ContentEditor web part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of writing the call in `href`, call it `onclick` event

```
function ChangeLanguage(value) {
    var today = new Date();
    var oneYear = new Date(today.getTime() + 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    var url = window.location.href;
    document.cookie = "lcid=" + value + ";path=/;expires=" + oneYear.toGMTString();
    window.location.href = url;
}


<a href="#" onclick="javascript:ChangeLanguage(1053);">Change Language</a>
```

Comment: Ok. But problem is not on <a href="javascript:ChangeLanguage(1053)"></a>. My question is: can we use java script function on custom aspx page ? As i know, on custom aspx page, only content Controls are allowed. any idea to slove this problem

Comment: @Mustafa646 is it? I thought there isn't any problem in using JavaScript in custom application pages.. [Setting Up an Application Page for JavaScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee535709(v=office.14).aspx)